# Linq select returns wrong result when Ternary conditional operator used within lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string that is in Arabic, I'm trying to change the numeric values in it to English and leave the rest untouched.

This is my string:

```
string x = "یکشنبه ۲۳ دی ۱۳۹۷ ۱۰:۳۰:۰۰"
```

and this is how I convert it:

```
x = string.Join("", x.Select(a => a >= '۰' || a <= '۹' ? (char)(48 + a - '۰') : a));
```

The funny thing is the part that should convert numeric characters to English works correctly, but the part that returns the character itself (untouched) changes. this the result of this conversion:

`￩ｴﾆｨﾇ怒23怒ｯ怒1397怒10梁30梁00`

Comment: i suggest instead of doing this manually you use [`char.GetNumericValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) result `: یکشنبه 23 دی 1397 10:30:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your condition - change `||` to `&&` and replace `۱` with `۰`

```
x = string.Join("", x.Select(a => a >= '۰' && a <= '۹' ? (char)(48 + a - '۰') : a));
```

Comment: You are right, I am really ashamed of such a noob mistake